# python overwrite and append to text file

Tags: python

Iam new to python scripting.Please help me to open text file in overwrite and append mode
I want to overwrite text file which is already there for the first time looping starts and from next loop onwards , it should append the line to that text file.
Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
with open('/path/to/file', 'w') as outFile:
  outFile.write("new contents\n")
```

That's it!  Using `with` you do not even need to close the file yourself.